# Replace character in line inside a file

Tags: python, file

I have these different lines with values in a text file

```
sample1:1
sample2:1
sample3:0
sample4:15
sample5:500
```

and I want the number after the ":" to be updated sometimes
I know I can split the name by ":" and get a list with 2 values.

```
f = open("test.txt","r")
lines = f.readlines()
lineSplit = lines[0].split(":",1)
lineSplit[1] #this is the value I want to change
```

im not quite sure how to update the lineSplit[1] value with the write functions

Comment: Are you trying to write back to a file or ... ?

Comment: yes just trying to replace the number with a new number really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `fileinput` module, if you're trying to modify the same file:

```
>>> strs = "sample4:15"
```

Take the advantage of sequence unpacking to store the results in variables after splitting.

```
>>> sample, value = strs.split(':')
>>> sample
'sample4'
>>> value
'15'
```

Code:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace = True):
    sample, value = line.split(':')
    value = int(value)     #convert value to int for calculation purpose
    if some_condition: 
           # do some calculations on sample and value
           # modify sample, value if required 

    #now the write the data(either modified or still the old one) to back to file
    print "{}:{}".format(sample, value)
```

Comment: can I use this to just update a some of the lines rather then all of them?

Comment: @user2117821 you can add a simple `if` condition to check whether you want to modify the data or not.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, meaning, you can't assign new values inside them by index.
But you can split up the whole file into a list of lines, and change individual lines (strings) entirely. This is what you're doing in lineSplit[1] = A_NEW_INTEGER

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if condition:
        lineSplit = line.split(':')
        lineSplit[1] = new_integer
        lines[i] = ':'.join(lineSplit)
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something as such (assuming that each first element before `:` is indeed a key):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('fin') as fin:
    samples = OrderedDict(line.split(':', 1) for line in fin)

samples['sample3'] = 'something else'

with open('output') as fout:
    lines = (':'.join(el) + '\n' for el in samples.iteritems())
    fout.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `csv` module (`:` is a column delimiter in your case).

Assuming there is a `test.txt` file with the following content:

```
sample1:1
sample2:1
sample3:0
sample4:15
sample5:500
```

And you need to increment each value. Here's how you can do it:

```
import csv


# read the file
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=":")
    lines = [line for line in reader]


# write the file
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=":")
    for line in lines:
        # edit the data here

        # e.g. increment each value
        line[1] = int(line[1]) + 1
    writer.writerows(lines)
```

The contents of `test.txt` now is:

```
sample1:2
sample2:2
sample3:1
sample4:16
sample5:501
```

But, anyway, `fileinput` sounds more logical to use in your case (editing the same file).

Hope that helps.